# Node FS ENOENT error

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to make this script create a directory, then write stuff in it. Simple XML dumps & stuff.

I cant get anything of FS to work. isDirectory, createDirectory, readFile, writeFile. My reading in another SO post suggested a lot of changes to fs.stat().

I already set the permissions for the folder, so it should not be having any permissions problem (Windows).

My 1st step in checking for previous files & creating new or opening them:

```
. . .

var logsDir = './logs/';
var logAccess = logsDir + 'stuff.log';

try {   // The code says its an ENOENT
    console.log(fs.statSync(logsDir))

    if (!fs.statSync(logsDir).isDirectory()) {
        fs.mkdirSync(logsDir);
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.error('Error   ' + e.code);
}

try {   // Another ENOENT
    if (!fs.statSync(logAccess).isFile()) {
        fs.writeFileSync(logAccess, 'die', 'utf8');
    }
    //data = fs.readFileSync(logAccess, 'utf8');
} catch (e) {
    console.error('Error   errors are dumb');
}

. . .
```

Comment: it seems like Windows not recognize the "./folder", try first with the full path

Comment: Try `var logsDir = __dirname + '/logs/';` You might be calling the script from a directory where `logs` does not exist.

Comment: Actually the @usandfriends 's comment is better than mine, so, you should try what he said.

Comment: I went & tried both. Neither works

Comment: Does `logs` even exist in general (in the directory from where you are calling the script and where the script is actually located)?

Comment: Have you checked if your npm folder exists as it is stated here [ENOENT](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#error-enoent-stat-cusersuserappdataroamingnpm-on-windows-7)?

Answer (score 0):

```
fs.stat(logsDir, function(err,stat){
    try{
    if(err)
    {
        var e = err.code;
        throw e;
    }
        }
        catch(e)
        {
          if(e == 'ENOENT')
            {
             fs.mkdir(logsDir);   
            }
        else
            {
        console.log('Some other error   ' + err.code);
            }  
        }
});

fs.stat(logAccess, function(err,stat){
    try{
    if(err)
    {
        var e = err.code;
        throw e;
    }
        }
        catch(e)
        {
          if(e == 'ENOENT')
            {
             fs.writeFileSync(logAccess, 'die', 'utf8');   
            }
        else
            {
        console.log('Some other error   ' + err.code);
            }  
        }
});
```

Comment: You should use var fs = require('fs');

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var logsDir = './logs/';
var logAccess = logsDir + 'stuff.log';

 function directoryExits(logsDir){
 try {   
 return fs.statSync(logsDir).isDirectory();   
 } catch (err) {
 return false;
 }
}

  function fileExits(logAccess){
  try {   
   return fs.statSync(logAccess).isFile();     
   } catch (err) {
    return false;
   }
 }

var statsDir = directoryExits(logsDir);
var statsFile = fileExits(logAccess);
  if(!statsDir)
  {
  fs.mkdirSync(logsDir);   
  console.log("Directory Created")
  }
  else
  console.log('Directory already exists'); 
    if(!statsFile)
    {
    fs.writeFileSync(logAccess, 'die', 'utf8');
    }
    else
    console.log('File already exists');


app.listen(4000, function(){
console.log('Server running '); 
});
```

Comment: both answers can be used